# Docker make environment variable unwritable

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia

I have a machine learning rig with 6 v100's and people can access them through Jupyter inside a Docker container. I want to control who uses which graphic card so I have to set an environment variable.

So, I want to set the environment variable `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to a specific graphic card. But in Jupyter (runs on the docker container) users can edit this variable and so everyone could access every GPU.

How can I make this variable unwritable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `readonly NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to some start file of linux(maybe .bashrc), use `-e` to set `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`'s default value when start container.

Then user can not change it in jupyter.

Comment: Thanks! The "readonly NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" have to be set on the docker containers os i guess?

Comment: How can I reload nvidia so i see changes with NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES

Comment: Restart or re-setup a container, the NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES will be applied for your environment I think. I am not familar with gpu related, but if just a environment variable, I think it works same with other application.

Comment: `readonly` is a shell extension specific to `bash` and other shells, and doesn't affect subprocesses.  I don't think this will solve the OP's question, and may not work if the container doesn't include bash and/or doesn't run shell startup scripts (both are pretty common).

Comment: But op use jupyter，limit scenario, although not perfect solution for every scenario